# Publishing to Azure without taking the site down

Tags: asp.net, azure, web

I am relatively new to this field although I've been a programmer for years.

My company has a website hosted in Azure. I am the one that performs the "Publish" action after confirming that the team finished developing a certain module. However, I have to take the site down on every publish (adding the app_offline.htm while copying dll's, aspx files etc.).

This seems redundant, right? there should be a better way to do it.

I was thinking of the obvious, two servers that while I "talk" to one the other take all the traffic, and afterwards they sync or I can make a publish to the second.

Environment: VisualStudio2013, AzureWebSite, ASP.NET 4.0.

Please share your thoughts, knowledge or even just where should I start my investigation from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a second deployment slot. Publish to the inactive slot and then swap the slots when you're ready. After you switch slots, the old active slot will become the new inactive one, so you can just rinse and repeat as required everytime you need to do a publish.

Here's a backgrounder: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

Answer (score 0):

Two servers behind azure traffic manager. One server is the production one, the other is the "next version server".

Simply update the "next version server" and test it to see if things are working, and after validating this, swap the traffic manager to pass all the traffic to this server. Now the old server becomes the "next version server".

BTW, this also gives you the option to return to the previous version if your latest version was "not so good" :-)